# Code::Blocks crashes on Run Project

Tags: crash, codeblocks, glfw

I created a project from the "GLFW project" template in CodeBlocks 13.12 and hit F8 to run it. That's all. And what I got is an error as follows:

> **Cross-platform IDE built around wxWidgets, designed to be extensible and configurable. has stopped working**
>
> A problem caused the program to stop working correctly. Windows will close the program and notify you if a solution is available.

(it's using CB's *description* "Cross-platform ..." as its *name* here, apparently)

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The path to my project had some Cyrillic characters in it. I fixed it to consist of Latin characters only and the crash went away.

Comment: Hi, it is a CodeBlocks' bug, see: http://sourceforge.net/p/codeblocks/tickets/108

Answer (score 0):

This bug appears also when the path contains **Romanian characters** like: **ă â î ș ț**. If anyone sees this answer, just make sure your path contains only Latin characters.